# Make gravity in HTML5 canvas work twice

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Au6br/13/

The problem is when I keep pressing `keydown.up` the player jump multiple times. What I want is to define a variable called `JumpCount` so when the player jump if the jump variable is greater than this value the jumping stop.

```
  Character.prototype.Jump = function () { // Jumping
            character.MaxJump += gravity;
            character.y += character.MaxJump;

            if (keydown.up) {
                if (!character.jumping) {
                    character.jumping = true;
                    character.Pos = 4;
                    character.Row = 2;
                    character.h = 23;
                    character.MaxJump = -character.sp * 2.5;
                }
            }
            if (character.y >= ch - character.h) { // if the character is under the bottom
                character.y = ch - character.h;
                character.jumping = false;
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you can jump when you're not on the ground. It's because of the `Onground` function.

Replace this :

```
return this.y <= ch - this.h;
```

With this :

```
return this.y >= ch - this.h;
```

You should also use this function in `Jump` to avoid duplicate code :

```
if (character.Onground()) { // if the character is under the bottom
    character.y = ch - character.h;
    character.jumping = false;
}
```

Counting the jumps (I assume you want to make double jumps) can't work as long as you test `if(keydown.up)`. When you press the UP key, this value will be true for more than one frame (depending on the duration the player presses it), so you'll never be able to correctly count the number of jumps. You must bind the jump on the `onkeydown` event, which is called once. After that, it will be simple to replace character.jumping with an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
Character.prototype.Jump = function () {
    character.MaxJump += gravity;
    character.y += character.MaxJump;

    if (keydown.up) {
        if (character.CurrentJumps < character.JumpCount) {
            character.CurrentJumps++
            character.Pos = 4;
            character.Row = 2;
            character.h = 23;
            character.MaxJump = -character.sp * 2.5;
        }
    }
    if (character.y >= ch - character.h) {
        character.y = ch - character.h;
        character.CurrentJumps = 0
    }
};
```

Were JumpCount is the max jumps, and CurrentJumps is the currently done jumps

And an example to set to double jump:

```
character.JumpCount = 2 // 2 Jumps
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you add a variable called `jumpCount` or something that you increase every time the character jumps. Only allow the character to jump if `jumpCount` is smaller or equal to the number of jumps you like the character to be able to do. Then just set `jumpCount` to zero when the player touches the floor. This also gets rid of your `jumping` variable since this would mean the same thing as `jumpCount === 0`.

Comment: In addition to this I think colliding with certain objects should fire an event. Whenever you collide with those objects the character should reset jump count.

Comment: well i tried that actually but it didn't work for me and as u can see i did declare a variable called jumpcount in my code can u update my jsfiddle please

Comment: @Sora Murplyx's answer is essentially the same as what I proposed. Have you tried his code? That in conjunction with sebcap26's onground suggestion would be a good start.